# How to operate Moving Average on List of Lists?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, moving-average

I have a list of lists of numbers in mathematica, i.e.

```
{{a, b, c, d, e},{f, g, h, i, j}}
```

and I want to operate MovingAverage on each sublist.

However,

MovingAverage[listOfLists,{movingAverageElementChoice,movingAverageElementChoice}] simply returns a one dimensional list, which is the number of elements in the jth column divided by numberOfSublists

I have tried a lot, please help!

I have tried MovingAverage[listOfLists,movingAverageElementChoice]

kineticsData8219K6Averaged =
MovingAverage[kineticsData8219K6, {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}];

I want it to output each sublist operated on by MovingAverage

Answer (score 1):

You want to do the same thing to every element of a list. You should think of `Map` in almost every situation like this. Each of your elements just happen to be lists, but that isn't an issue. So

```
data={{a, b, c, d, e},{f, g, h, i, j}};
Map[MovingAverage[#, 2]&, data]
```

gives you the result

```
{{(a+b)/2, (b+c)/2, (c+d)/2, (d+e)/2}, {(f+g)/2, (g+h)/2, (h+i)/2, (i+j)/2}}
```

And you can provide additional arguments inside that `MovingAverage` to modify the behavior to match what you need. The `#` will be replaced one at a time by each list inside `data` and the result of each of those `MovingAverage` will be put into a list and returned to you.